# How to set the 'selected option' of a select dropdown list country and state

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, wordpress, drop-down-menu

My filter search flowing :

```
case 'region_state':
$output .= '
<div class="clear"></div>
<label><st>' . __( "Country", AT_TEXTDOMAIN ) . ':</s2></label>
<div class="select_box_1">
    <select name="region_id" id="region_id" class="custom-select select_1">';
    $output .= '<option value="0">' . __( "All", AT_TEXTDOMAIN ) . '</option>';
    foreach ($view->add_widget( 'reference_widget', array( 'method' => 'get_regions' ), true ) as $key => $value) {
        $output .= '<option value="' . $value['id'] . '">' . $value['name'] . '</option>';
      }
    // foreach (AT_VC_Helper::get_manufacturers() as $value => $key) {
    //  $output .= '<option value="' . $key. '">' . $value . '</option>';
    // }
    $output .= '
    </select>
    </div>
    <label><s3>' . __( "State", AT_TEXTDOMAIN ) . ':</s3></label>
    <div class="select_box_1">
      <select name="state_id" id="state_id" class="custom-select select_1">
        <option>All</option>
      </select>
    </div>';
    $output .= '<input type="submit" value="' . __( "Search", AT_TEXTDOMAIN ) . '" class="btn_search btn-1 float-right" id="search_car_shortcode1"/>';
            break;
```

Data Become from reference_widget WordPress admin  , I want 1 country for Ex USA State : new york, By default.

Comment: You have 2 choices. Put a `selected` attribute on the option you want to be selected when constructing the HTML, or execute JS once the select box is ready and set it's value to what you need. I know it's stupid that `select` elements do not honor a `value` attribute, but that isin't the worst thing about the DOM... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to test on each loop if the value you are on is the one that should be 
"selected".

```
// the value you want to be selected
$region_id = $_REQUEST['region_id'];
// loop through the options
foreach ( $view->add_widget( 'reference_widget', array( 'method' => 'get_regions' ), true ) as $key => $value ){
    // if the value matches, we want to output "selected"
    $selected = ( $region_id == $value )? ' selected' : '';
    $output .= '<option value="' . $value['id'] . '"' . $selected . '>' . $value['name'] . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you doublesharp , All Done.